# Determining the specific diffraction lines when 2 monochromatic beams are incident on a diffraction grating

Tags: homework-and-exercises, diffraction, superposition

I am wondering whether it is possible to determine the exact colour permutation for the diffraction lines from only the following given information:

"When monochromatic red and monochromatic violet light are incident on a
diffraction grating, it is found that the fourth line observed, not counting the
undiffracted zero order line, is a superposition of red and violet light. Explain this
observation and specify the first four lines."

Let the mth order line relate to red light, and nth order relate to violet light.

As the wavelength of red light is longer than the wavelength of violet light, the frequency of violet lines is greater than red lines. ( ie n>m>=1 )
As the 4th line is a superposition, we have m+n = 5 (4 + 1 as the fourth line is counted double).

From the two constraints we get two combinations (n,m) = (4, 1) or (3, 2), corresponding to (voilet, voilet, voilet, voilet+red) or (voilet, red, voilet, voilet+red) lines seen.

Is there any way to distinguish between these possibilities further?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the wavelengths for violet and red light, you will find that violet is about half the wavelength of red.

Comment: So we would need extra information, i.e. the ratio of the wavelengths of the red and violet light?